# Custom Background: Can't Set Color Default

Tags: custom-background

I'm using the standard WP Custom Backgrounds feature, however, the color is defaulting to #166b4c and I'm unsure why.  #166b4c does not appear in my stylesheet.  Below is my code.

```
    add_theme_support( 'custom-background' );
    $defaults = array(
        'default-color'          => '000',
        'default-image'          => '',
        'wp-head-callback'       => '_custom_background_cb',
        'admin-head-callback'    => '',
        'admin-preview-callback' => ''
    );

add_theme_support( 'custom-background', $defaults);
```

Live example: http://themeforward.com/demo2/

Comment: Can you post an URL?

Comment: Posted, see updated question.

Comment: Two different rules for `body.custom-background` are being inserted. Any idea why that is? View source to see what I mean.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it.  I had rogue code floating around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the `$defaults` as the second parameter to `add_theme_support()` per the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support#Custom_Background)

```
$defaults = array(
    'default-color'          => '000000',
    'default-image'          => '',
    'wp-head-callback'       => '_custom_background_cb',
    'admin-head-callback'    => '',
    'admin-preview-callback' => ''
);

add_theme_support( 'custom-background', $defaults);
```

Comment: For some reason this is still not changing the background color.  Background images work, but not color.